# why a friend function take class reference as parameter defined in class scope can be find by compiler?

Tags: c++

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class People {
private:
    double hight;
    double weight;

public:
    friend void run()
    {
        cout << " I started running!";
    }
};

int main()
{
    People Amy;
    run();
}
```

if i compile it,it will throw a error:‘run’ was not declared in this scope

```cpp
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;

class People {
private:
    double hight;
    double weight;

public:
    friend void run(People&) { cout << " I started running!"; }
};

int main()
{
    People Amy;
    run(Amy);
}
```

now i do so,it compile successfully,i just I just changed the parameter that 'run' function takes.

why a friend function take class reference as parameter defined in class scope can be find by compiler?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't post code as image.

Comment: Please provide code in text, not as images. It's even easier just to copy paste than create a screenshot, upload it and insert the link...

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1387438

Comment: replace   run(Amy);     by     Amy.run();

Comment: Do you know the purpose of the `friend` keyword? Are you confusing it with `static`?

Comment: @jo_ `run` is not a member function. `Amy.run();` won't work.

Comment: The way you have it declared, `run` is a *hidden friend* (hidden from normal lookup).  The second example has a `People&` parameter, which means `run` can be found through ADL.  But the first example without any parameters, as given there is no way to access the hidden friend.  (The given answers show how to unhide the friend.)

Answer (score 1):

While the `run` function isn't a ,member function, it's also not declared in the global scope meaning it's not possible to find it using normal lookup. That it is found in the second example is because of [*argument dependent lookup* (or ADL)](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).

The simplest solution is to also declare it in the global scope:

```
struct People
{
    ...
    friend void run() { ... };
};

// Declare function in global scope
void run();
```

Answer (score -1):

You need a delcaration of `run` so you can call it in main:

```
void run();

struct People { /* including a definition of run */ }; 

int main() {
     run();
}
```

When `run` takes a `People` as parameter then the declaration is found via [ADL](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/adl).